# Were priests just dressed in secular garb in the early church?

Tags: early-church, liturgy, vestments

I was reading about the gift that President Biden gave to Pope Francis and wondering what a "Fiddleback Chasuble" was.  What I stumbled upon on wikipedia was this interesting tidbit that it pulls from the old Catholic Encylopedia:

> The priest in discharging his sacred functions at the altar was dressed as in civil life, but the custom probably grew up of reserving for this purpose garments that were newer and cleaner than those used in his daily ministry, and out of this gradually developed the conception of a special liturgical attire
>
> https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03639a.htm

I was skeptical reading this in wikipedia, but I trust the Catholic Encyclopedia.  Now, this might have made sense in the olden days, but with all the movies (with all their great information and well research facts about traditional religion) that have been produced in the last hundred years, one might be apt to think that the vestments of the Catholic priesthood were anything except secular garb as they seem to resemble Jewish or pagan priests.  Is this just an anachronism?  What  evidence do "ecclesiologists" have that early priests were just wearing their Sunday best, like everyone else?

Comment: Jesus said 'Beware of them that go in long robes'. It seems that religious leaders (as a class) always desire to set themselves apart by means of distinctive clothing.

Comment: @nigelj  "The modern man thought Becket's robes too rich and his meals too poor. But then the modern man was really exceptional in history; no man before ever ate such elaborate dinners in such ugly clothes. ... The man who disliked vestments wore a pair of preposterous trousers. And surely if there was any insanity involved in the matter at all it was in the trousers, not in the simply falling robe " https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/130/pg130.html just seems odd to think that early priests were wearing the functional equivalent of business casual.

Comment: Indeed, it was not only what they were wearing in civil life but they also wore a stole. In ancient Rome, the stole was worn by a "leading" person in some assembly: In a court trial, the judge wore a stole; in a city council meeting, the mayor wore a stole. So the priests were dressed like a judge or a mayor was dressed.

Comment: What else would they have worn, back before the specialized priestly garbs were invented? Heck, if they had worn special garb, the Romans would have just been able to use the ownership of it as an excuse to kill them.

Comment: The (liturgical) garments, just like the (Latin) language, are simply the ones employed by people at the time; elders or presbyters (hence the word priest) were not invented by Christianity from scratch, but were simply a previous Jewish institution (like the Passover meal, for instance), which the new emerging religion simply adopted and reinterpreted. As entire Jewish communities, whether from Israel or the diaspora, along with their elders or leaders, joined the growing movement, they simply took their customs and traditions along with them.

Comment: @lucian, that was my assumption.  But it's not what apparently is the case.  I thought the garb was Jewish -> Christians but "historians" say it's Roman.  Doesn't seem like it oughta be both.

Comment: @PeterTurner: That's not particularly important, since Greek-Roman togas were not that different from Semitic dress, as worn even today by traditional Arabs. Furthermore, said Romans did not convert in a vacuum; as already stated, the faith basically spread from mainland Judaism to the [Hellenized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_Judaism) diaspora, then to [God-fearers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God-fearer) or proselytes, then to Gentiles proper. Likewise, traditional Protestant pastors are dressed in liturgical black gowns, characteristic of the late medieval and early modern era.

Answer (score 2):

**Were priests just dressed in secular garb in the early church?**

Yes.

> It seems that in the early centuries of Christianity **no distinctive dress** was adopted by ecclesiastics. [1](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04419b.htm)

> In the **sixth and following centuries** we find that in Rome and in countries near Rome the civil dress of the clergy **began markedly to differ** from that of the laity, the reason probably being that the former adhered to the old Roman type of costume with its long tunic and voluminous cloak, representing the toga, whereas the laity were increasingly inclined to adopt the short tunic, with breeches and mantle, of the gens braccata, i.e. the Northern barbarians, who were now the masters of Italy. [1](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04419b.htm)

The article I cited further explains how we know.